# Managing two different git repositories of the same code

Tags: git, merge, repo

I want to be able to have two different repositories of the same code, with different people committing work to each of them. I can't fork. One is the "master repository" if you will, but I do want to be able to merge in changes from the "secondary repository" into the master repository. Is this possible?

Comment: Git branches is the standard pattern here. Why does this not suit your use case?

Comment: They have to be separate repositories due to only a single account having access to the master repository.  @emeraldjava

Comment: Set up a second remote on your local repo and you will be able to see (and work with) both repos.

Comment: This is just how dvcs's work, what's the problem here? repo boundaries don't matter, what matters is the history. fetch anything from any repo that'll talk to you, push anything to any repo that'll have you. Welcome to Git.